# How to code special character for SQL in R

Tags: sql, r, encoding

I would like to connect to ODBC data source from R, but the connection as well as the column names which I would like to read contain special characters. How can these special characters be transcript so that R understands them?

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc(), "Name with ö character")
dbGetQuery(con, 'select [Cölumn] from Table')
```

I want to run the script with task scheduler so simply running it as it is written does not help.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?  In SQL Server and Access, your current select query should already be valid (encoding issues aside).

Comment: Access, but as mentioned, Rscript run by Task scheduler does not read it with the same encoding. I get this answer con <- dbConnect(odbc(), "Name with Ã¶ character") 
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:983: IM002: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Answer (score 0):

After playing with it a bit more I found that:

- saving the code in system encryption
- replacing the column's local character without punctuation

makes it work:

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc(), "Name with ö character")
dbGetQuery(con, 'select [Column] from Table') #ö replaced by o
```